How would creatures in a methane ocean breathe?
The planet I'm building is similar to Titan, and has an atmosphere that's around 6 times as dense as Earth's, while having around 63% the surface gravity. The planet is around 100 Kelvin on average.
I'm making a bunch of sea-creatures for my planet, but I'm wondering how their respiratory system would work due to the rarity of oxygen. Basically, I'm asking what they would breathe, and what they would breathe out as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome Nervous. Could you tell us about what's available for them to breath? It's not much good us guessing at their metabolism if it's not there.

Yep, what @Escapeddentalpatient. said, what are they breathing in? the way you've worded that suggests it's not necessarily methane, so .. that there may be other atmosphere components available?

@Community dear community bot (talking to inanimate objects again  my shrink will love this, if I had one ) the question is perfectly clear .. he wants to know what what would be, and the output of, an appropriate metabolic process (to seve in lieu of our breathing in oxygen and out CO2) in a methane environment .. your algorithms can maybe do with a little tweak in this instance

How would they breathe? At 100 K, few materials have any flexibility. There's also little chemistry that spontaneously happens at that temperature. Most materials are frozen solid and not soluble to any significant degree in liquid methane. Even if it can support life (maybe the atmosphere lets more light penetrate, enough for photochemistry?), can it muster the level of energy required for something like breathing? Even plants on Earth can't manage that.

Poorly.  rimshot I'll see myself out.

I'm voting to close as Needs More Details and I'm hoping the question will be closed quickly. I think there's an opportunity here, but the question as written requires inventing the entirety of life on Titan before we can address the question. That violates the Book Rule in spades. Worse, at first blush it appears there's NOTHING on Titan that can be used to replace oxygen as the oxidizer of life (see this question, which your question might actually duplicate... from a certain point of view... (*Continued*)

... but it's an important point of view.) Frankly, neither Nitrogen nor hydrogen can be used to replace oxygen. At first blush hydrogen might, but it's a reducer (giver of electrons), not an oxidizer (taker of electrons). So, before you can actually ask the question you're asking, we need to ask some very much more fundamental questions... like what would be the oxidizer and what would be the "universal solvent." NOTE: If you're looking to invent "realistic" life on (e.g.) Titan, you need to demonstrate you've done your research. There's a lot of speculation out there already.

There are bacteria called Methanotrophs, which can metabolize methane with or without oxygen, but I agree that the temperature is a bigger problem than the methane. Would this be a question that would benefit from the Sandbox?

@Yeslek71 those generally reduce some oxygen-containing compound in the process. Another issue is that the end products of CO2 and H2O are solids that aren't going to do much chemistry at 100 K, so you don't have any kind of closed cycle, you're consuming some environmental source which will be exhausted.
